# How to get JDBC connection id?

Tags: jdbc, database-connection

I need to get the JDBC connection id(UUID) with Connection object. Is there is any way to get the connection id?

Comment: What is the JDBC connection id (UUID), as far as I know there is no such thing. If you are talking about a specific JDBC driver or database system, then please specify that.

Comment: When i am connecting to Database there is one unique id they are maintaining inside thession. Suppose if my sql server gets restarted means my existing connection object throws error. If i can able to get that unique id i can able to check the condition and reconnect again

Comment: Is there any update for this? I want to get the identifier of each database connection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you meen "sql-connection to sql-server", then jdbc has no standard instruments for this. Here is handmade example for jdbc:mysql (beware - Reflection and restricted characters):

```
    private long getJdbcConnectionId(Connection conn) {
    long cid = 0;
    try {
        Field f_conn__conn = conn.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("_conn");
        f_conn__conn.setAccessible(true);
        Object o_conn__conn = f_conn__conn.get(conn);
        Field f_conn__conn__conn = o_conn__conn.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("_conn");
        f_conn__conn__conn.setAccessible(true);
        Object o_conn__conn__conn = f_conn__conn__conn.get(o_conn__conn);
        Field f_connectionId = o_conn__conn__conn.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("connectionId");
        f_connectionId.setAccessible(true);
        cid = f_connectionId.getLong(o_conn__conn__conn);
        f_connectionId.setAccessible(false);
        f_conn__conn__conn.setAccessible(false);
        f_conn__conn.setAccessible(false);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cid;
}
```

Comment: @verystrongjoe  )))) it's a java, but it uses java-unrecommended (not restricted!!!) characters. All you need - to replace '$' with '_' or anything you wish.  ok. i'l do it myself

Comment: One more:  I made it for Jdbc4connection class.

Comment: thanks. I will try it. I am making application monitoring solution. and this code will be used in where needs to be identify each connection.

Comment: i got a error with this code. connectionId can't be found. It seemed to have changed or have other field name.

Comment: @verystrongjoe  It can be named another way (in case of another SDK). Good news - the hierarchy Connection._conn._conn is present in your case.
Try to look the fields by debugger

Comment: Fortunately. Yes. It seems to have the _conn field. But which class should I have to debug into?

Comment: @verystrongjoe  wow... the question is confusing, cause i know neither SDK, nor jdbc-library you are using. And it seems you are not familiar with debugger(?).
well, i'm using IDEA, so tracing the executing of my getJdbcConnectionId() i see in debugger window the current "class" instance of Connection-interface. I see in this window it's class-name (in my case JDBC4Connection), it's fields, the fields inside this fields (did you look inside them?) and looking through this nested hierarchy i've got a neccessary field.
But, imho, the describing of "debug-methodology" is out of this topic

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

ok this way to avoid compile-time coupling, using reflection

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
...
public String getMysqlConnectionId()
{
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://host:3306/schema", "myuser", "mypassword");

        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection");

        Object o = connection.unwrap(clazz);

        return (String) clazz.getMethod("getId").invoke(o).toString();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

---

By casting your `java.sql.Connection` object to `com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection` and using `getId()`

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection;
...
public long getMysqlConnectionId()
{
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://host:3306/schema", "myuser", "mypassword");

    // would throw a ClassCastException in case this is not a mysql one, of course
    return ((MySQLConnection) connection).getId();
}
```

But this is sort of **terribly coupling** your project to MySQL at compile time

note: I won't be offended when I get down-voted for this, it is sort of deserved ;-)

```
<!-- pom.xml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>x.y.z</version>
</dependency>
```

Some other people apparently are using `connection.unwrap(com.mysql.jdbc.MySQLConnection)` which might feels a bit more appropriate, yet does not remove the compile-time coupling to `com.mysql`
https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/9425

Answer (score -1):

Here is my example how to get Oracle SID:

```
    public int getConnectionSid() {
    try {
        if (connection == null || connection.isClosed())                
            return -1;            
        if (connectionSid == -1) {                
            try { 
                Method method = connection.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getSessionId", null);
                method.setAccessible(true);
                connectionSid = (Integer)method.invoke(nativeConnection, null);                    
                method.setAccessible(false);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                return -1;
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                return -1;
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return connectionSid;
    } catch (SQLException e) {            
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: What is native connection?

Comment: nativeConnection is java.sql.Connection object. I forgot to mention that connection is just a wrapper around java.sql.Connection.